# How to call a function by name using GObject?

Tags: c, glib, gobject

That function I want to call using GObject does look like the following:

```
char * some_object_fun(SomeObject *self, char *input);
```

Is there a good way to achieve this? I would be very interested in an elegant solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C doesn't really support introspection/reflection like you may be used to if you're coming from something like Python, PHP, Java, etc.

I don't know that I'd call it "elegant", but most operating systems offer a way to get the address of a public symbol, so if your symbol is public you can use that, cast it to a function pointer of the appropriate type, then invoke the function.  On POSIX, the relevant functions are called `dlopen` and `dlsym`.  On Windows, `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`.

Your tags mention GObject, so that simplifies things a bit; you can just use [`g_module_open`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Dynamic-Loading-of-Modules.html#g-module-open) and [`g_module_symbol`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Dynamic-Loading-of-Modules.html#g-module-symbol) (which are basically abstractions over the functions I mentioned above).

The code would look something like:

```
char* (* sym)(SomeObject*, char*);
GModule* module = g_module_open(NULL, 0);
sym = g_module_symbol("some_object_fun");
sym(instance, input);
g_module_close(module);
```

Plus some error handling, of course, but you should be able to figure that part out.